# Could not consume Asp.net web API in Edge

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-edge

Thanks in advance,

We have created Asp.net web API. We are trying to consume the API through our front end application. We can consume the API with google chrome, firefox. 
But not able to consume this API with Microsoft Edge. 
When we are trying to hit the URL with "GET" Request we are getting the following response:

`{Response code:0}`

We tried the same with "Post" Request and we are getting the same response as previous.

**Error message:**

[image: error message]

Seems like a weird error. I tried all the solution on the internet could not resolve this. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should describe some of the solutions you tried so others don't go over the same ground when trying to help you. [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried and your research, and show what results you get. Show your [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: If some Javascript code throws, post the Javascript code. ASP.NET Web API is just an HTTP service, it doesn't produce Javascript nor does it affect how clients run.

Comment: To debug any kind of HTTP API use a browser's Network window in the development tools. What is being sent? What is being returned?